# how could I remove the characters from this string

Tags: python

I am trying to remove any numbers from a set of string and returning just the characters.

```
def standardize_names(employee_name):
    employee_name.strip()
    print(employee_name)
    for x in employee_name:
        if x.isnumeric():
            employee_name.replace(x, '')
    print(employee_name)
            
            
            
standardize_names("     Hermione7 gR1nger  ")
```

I tried this but it just returns the same string again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this cold, without testing but I think you should be able to do the following:

```
def standardize_names(employee_name):
    employee_name = employee_name.strip()
    print(employee_name)
    name = ''
    for x in employee_name:
        if not x.isnumeric():
            name += x
    print(name)
```

Comment: You need to write  employee_name = employee_name.strip() since there are no in-place methods for strings.

Comment: your right, corrected.

Comment: This worked when I tried it on the OP's example.